# When do two topoi have the same cohomology of constant sheaves

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, topos-theory

Recently, I have some questions for some generalizations from algebraic topology.

I learn some homotopy theory in algebraic topology. We know that, if two spaces are homotopy, then they have same cohomology groups for constant sheaves.

I want to know if there are similar theory for topoi, such as homotopy theory for topoi?

Thanks for your answers

Comment: For $\infty$-topoi, one has the [shape](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/shape+of+an+%28infinity%2C1%29-topos) of the $\infty$-topos.

Comment: @Tim Campion   Thanks for your answer. I know nothing about $\infty$-topoi, but I think what you are saying is that, a topoi is a special case of $\infty$-topos, and in the theory of  $\infty$-topoi, we have a similar theory of homotopy?

Comment: @yulincai Precisely from any topos you can construct an ∞-topos (and viceversa - it's an adjunction) and every ∞-topos has a shape (which is something like a pro-homotopy type). In the case of the small étale topos of a scheme this is what's usually known as the étale homotopy type of the scheme. The connection with locally constant sheaves is explored in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.07155), and it does require some hypotheses on your topos to be well behaved.

Comment: For toposes of the form $\mathrm{Set}^G$, for a group $G$, you get just cohomology of $G$ with constant coefficients. There are many acyclic groups, having trivial cohomology with any constant coefficients. They will have different fundamental groups however, which is just $G$ in this case.

Comment: @DenisNardin   Thanks for your answer. I will check the related theory. In my case, what I care the most is, when do two topoi have the same cohomology for constant sheaves. Based on your answer, I think the answer should be "if their $\infty$-topoi have the same shapes" (of course, it is a sufficient condition). Is it right? Thanks.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Yes, I agree with what you said. Do we have similar sufficient condition, such  "homotopic" for two topoi to have cohomology with any constant coefficients?

Comment: @yulincai Although it is true that this kind of questions is subsumed by shape theory of $\infty$-topoi, with Marc Hoyois' paper on higher Galois theory essentially saying everything we need to know, there is a little book of Moerdijk called "Classifying spaces and classifying topoi" which studies this kind of things for $1$-topoi, and manipulates explicit homotopies and geometric realizations, with rather explicit (and nice) examples related to the theory of fofliations.

Comment: @Denis-CharlesCisinski  Thanks for your comment. The book you mentioned is helpful to me. I know where I can find the answers I need based on these very kind comments.

Answer (score 6):

There is a notion of the **étale homotopy type** of a (Grothendieck) topos, going back to Artin and Mazur (I think).
However, in classic "French" fashion they turned a theorem (in one setting) into a definition (in a more general setting): roughly speaking, two toposes have the same étale homotopy type if they have the same étale fundamental group and the same cohomology for all (constant sheaf) coefficients.
So perhaps this isn't what you're looking for, but let me continue.

Let $\mathcal{E}$ be a topos.
Artin and Mazur define the étale homotopy type of $\mathcal{E}$ under the assumption that $\mathcal{E}$ is locally connected, which for the purpose of this discussion means the unique colimit- and finite-limit-preserving functor $\Delta : \textbf{Set} \to \mathcal{E}$ has a left adjoint $\pi : \mathcal{E} \to \textbf{Set}$.
Let $\textbf{Hc} (\mathcal{E})$ be the category of hypercovers of the terminal object $1$ in $\mathcal{E}$.
(The objects are simplicial objects $K$ in $\mathcal{E}$ such that the unique morphism $K \to 1$ is a local trivial Kan fibration and the morphisms are *simplicial homotopy classes* of morphisms.)
Let $\mathcal{K} = \operatorname{Ho} \textbf{sSet}$ be the category of simplicial sets localised with respect to weak homotopy equivalences.
The étale homotopy type of $\mathcal{E}$, as defined by Artin and Mazur, is the following pro-object in $\mathcal{K}$:
$$\Pi (\mathcal{E}) = \varprojlim_{K : \textbf{Hc} (\mathcal{E})} \pi (K)$$
Here, $\pi (K)$ denotes the simplicial set obtained by applying $\pi : \mathcal{E} \to \textbf{Set}$ degreewise to the simplicial object $K$.
(The reason for using simplicial homotopy classes of morphisms in the definition of $\textbf{Hc} (\mathcal{E})$ is so that we get a cofiltered category.
This category is usually not small, but it is coinitially small, so we do indeed get a pro-object.)

Observe that, for a Kan complex $X$,
$$\textbf{Pro} (\mathcal{K}) (\Pi (\mathcal{E}), X) \cong \varinjlim_{K : \textbf{Hc} (\mathcal{E})^\textrm{op}} \mathcal{K} (\pi (K), X) \cong \varinjlim_{K : \textbf{Hc} (\mathcal{E})^\textrm{op}} \pi_0 [\textbf{s} \mathcal{E}] (K, \Delta (X))$$
where $\pi_0 [\textbf{s} \mathcal{E}]$ is the category of simplicial objects in $\mathcal{E}$ modulo simplicial homotopy.
The simplicial analogue of Verdier's hypercovering theorem states that the RHS computes $\pi_0 (\textbf{R} \Gamma (\Delta (X)))$, which you might interpret as analogous to $H_0$ of the derived global sections of a chain complex of sheaves.
This is literally the case when $X$ is a simplicial abelian group, so you can extract the classical Verdier hypercovering theorem from this.
Put it another way, the pro-object $\Pi (\mathcal{E})$ encodes enough information to determine the cohomology of constant sheaves on $\mathcal{E}$, which is what you wanted – but as I said in the first paragraph, in some sense the definition was constructed to make this true.

Now let me discuss the notion of **shape**, which has been mentioned in the comments.
The category $\mathcal{K}$ is not a pleasant category to work with, and $\textbf{Pro} (\mathcal{K})$ is even less pleasant.
The restriction to locally connected $\mathcal{E}$ is also somewhat unsatisfying.
In the years since Artin–Mazur new technologies have been developed for abstract homotopy theory and using this we obtain an improved version of the étale homotopy type.

First, we must obtain an $\infty$-topos from $\mathcal{E}$.
Take the category of simplicial objects in $\mathcal{E}$ and localise (in the $(\infty, 1)$-categorical sense now) with respect to local weak homotopy equivalences to obtain an $\infty$-topos $\tilde{\mathcal{E}}$.
Let $\mathcal{S}$ be the $(\infty, 1)$-category of $\infty$-groupoids.
The global sections functor $\Gamma : \tilde{\mathcal{E}} \to \mathcal{S}$ has a left adjoint $\Delta : \mathcal{S} \to \tilde{\mathcal{E}}$, and as before we are interested in the composite functor $X \mapsto \pi_0 (\Gamma (\Delta (X)))$.
Since $\Gamma$ is an accessible right adjoint and $\Delta$ is a left adjoint that preserves finite limits, the composite $\Gamma \Delta$ is an accessible functor that preserves finite limits.
The $(\infty, 1)$-category of accessible functors $\mathcal{S} \to \mathcal{S}$ that preserve finite limits is equivalent to the $(\infty, 1)$-category of pro-objects in $\mathcal{S}$, so $\Gamma \Delta$ corresponds to some pro-object $\Pi (\tilde{\mathcal{E}})$ – the shape of $\tilde{\mathcal{E}}$ is this object.
(Given an inverse diagram $T$ in $\mathcal{S}$, the functor $\varinjlim \mathcal{S} (T, -) : \mathcal{S} \to \mathcal{S}$ is an accessible functor that preserves finite limits; the fact is that all accessible functors $\mathcal{S} \to \mathcal{S}$ that preserve finite limits arise in this way.)

The advantage of the formulation of shape is that it is immediate how the shape encodes the cohomology of constant sheaves, but again this seems to be a trick – a different one from before, but in some sense there is still nothing deep going on.
One might even say there is even less depth here because even hypercovers have disappeared from view.
But perhaps this answers your question about whether there is a homotopy theory of toposes.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your clarification. Do you have good references for this theory?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the theory beyond the basic definitions. Moerdijk's book is probably the easiest way to get started.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions.